# Problem with SQL Server's default column property in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sql-server-express

I've already added defined the default value 'default.gif' to a column of datatype ntext.

then on the aspx page I placed a file upload control and take it's file name value as a parameter in an INSERT query to the column. what I was trying to do is to be able to point to a specific file when there's no one uploaded so every item will have a picture even the user didn't upload one!

what I get is an empty value in the field, not even null and not even an two quotations.

*Just blank! I wonder why it doesn't add the default value!*

Comment: If you go into the DB and manually insert a new row leaving the column set to null does it work?

Comment: @Zack - trying to insert a `NULL` doesn't cause the default to be used - it attempts to insert a `NULL`.

Comment: Presumably you send an INSERT statement to the DB even if the file upload control is empty.  Have you looked at this statement, does it set the field to an empty string?  If so that's your problem.

Comment: if you add a column to insert clause its default value would be overridden by parameter provided by insert clause. so if its empty jut dont add to insert.

Comment: @James, I think maybe this is it! .. but what I was attempting to do is to let the database have for example a default value 'defaultfile.jpg' so if the user didn't upload a picture it would still show a picture in his porfile! .. I set the parameter for the picture field to FileUploadControlInstance.FileName;

Comment: @adt, so I have to create two methods or two query statements !? .. one to use if there's a value in the upload file and another one that doesn't have a value for the upload file right ? and if I'm right, do you think it's a good solution!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for a column is only used when an `INSERT` operation is performed, and either:

- The column is not included in the column list for the insert operation, or,
- The column is included in the column list for the insert operation, but the corresponding position in the `VALUES` list is given as `DEFAULT`, e.g.:

`INSERT INTO Table1 (FileName,/* other columns */)`

`VALUES(DEFAULT,/* other values */)`

I'm guessing that whatever your data layer is (you haven't specified one, that I can see) is incapable of generating the `INSERT` statement in this form.

---

Your code:

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Teachers(Name, PictureFileName, Blog, IsAdmin) VALUES (@Name, @PictureFileName, @Blog, @IsAdmin);", conn))
```

You'll need to add some new code, something like:

```
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Teachers(Name, Blog, IsAdmin";
if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(/* Wherever you get the picture file name from */)
{
   insertStatement += ", PictureFileName";
}
insertStatement += ") VALUES (@Name, @Blog, @IsAdmin";
if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(/* Wherever you get the picture file name from */)
{
   insertStatement += ", @PictureFileName";
}
insertStatement += ");";
```

Then use that insertStatement variable in the `SqlCommand` constructor - you might want to make adding the `@PictureFileName` parameter conditional too, and if this is a performance critical portion of the app, you might want to use a stringbuilder to construct this insert statement, or use string formatting code.

Comment: I didn't quite get you but here's some of my DAL:
 using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Teachers(Name, PictureFileName, Blog, IsAdmin) VALUES (@Name, @PictureFileName, @Blog, @IsAdmin);", conn)) and it runs quite proper and insert the new items and I display them too .. but just the default property for the PictureFileName generates an empty string or something!

Comment: if picturefilename is empty dont add it to INSERT clause. so default value will be inserted.

Comment: so you're suggest the same thing as adt ? .. to have two different methods or queries to perform depending on whether there's a file uploaded or not ?

Comment: @IKashef - either way, you either need to prevent the column appearing in the column list of the insert (as I've demoed above with the code re-write), or you need the literal word `DEFAULT` to appear in the values list - either way, you're going to have to write code to specifically deal with this insert, in order to get the default value applied.

Comment: as i see you are using ado.net objects directly. so while preparing your query handle is filename string or empty and do not add it to the clause. instead of using this objects directly you should use some ORM framework .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I got it thanks. but I think I'll use two string variables (InsertQuery1 and InsertQuery2) then check if the FileName is empty so I would use one that excludes the pictureField and vice verse .. I think it's the same .. if you think otherwise please let me know!

Comment: @adt- But don't you think an ORM is a too much for such a small solvable problem .. if there's something that you see and I don't, please tell me =)!

Comment: @IKashef - yep, that works too. I went with the "build the insert string dynamically" - which you might want to do if there's more than one column with a default you want to use. If you have static strings and n columns with defaults, you might end up having to write 2^n separate strings...

Comment: Just a thought - but IMHO no problem is too small for an ORM.  LINQ to SQL is available out of the box and takes seconds to set up.  It takes longer to handwrite your ADO code than it does to set up a LINQ mapping.  Add to this that the thing about small problems is they tend to become bigger problems over time - so start as you mean to go on.

Comment: LINQ to SQL reputation is pretty bad! .. If I'll use an ORM, I'll think about a third-party projects like NHibernate. the only problem is that I have to learn how to write SQL in this whole new Framework! .. Thanks James though. +1 for your try to advise

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the query implementing the upload inserts a NULL into the column, not a blank string. Just passing through a blank string (i.e. '') does not necessarily mean you'll get the default value inserted.

Comment: Nor does inserting a `NULL` - try the following code in a query window - `create table T1 (ID int not null default 0) insert into T1(ID) VALUES(NULL)` - and you'll get an error

Comment: You are correct, I apologize. The DEFAULT value (literally DEFAULT) needs to be inserted, and it shouldn't be wrapped in quotes either. That's to say, if the column doesn't accept NULLs, as in your example.

Comment: So do I check if the upload control is empty then I set it's value to null (how to do that though!?) or should I make two methods or two insert queries one that includes the FileName to use if there's an uploaded file and the other that excludes it to use if there's no uploaded file ?

Comment: Have a look at Damiend_The_Unbeliever's answer. You'll have to write a bit of code to check whether the Value of the FileUpload control has got a value or not. I prefer doing everything in Stored Procedures myself, just because I have more control over the values being passed through and SQL injection attacks can be kept to a minimum.

Comment: @FarligOpptreden, Isn't using parameterized commands protects me from SQL injection attacks ?

Comment: It should yes, but as I mentioned my preference is using Stored Procedures as I have more control over the values being passed through. It means I can also make amendments to the updates / inserts without touching the application's code or recompiling and deploying it.